# google_sign_in failed problem is showing only when i am trying to upload my app on Playstore how to solve it?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-signin

[image: This problem is showing when i am trying to upload my app on Playstore it is not showing in my real device.]

This my code that I am using

````
 ```   void signWithGoogle(
    BuildContext context,
    WidgetRef? ref,
  ) async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();

      String? deviceToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

      UserModel.User user = UserModel.User(
        id: '',
        uniqueId: '',
        displayName: googleSignInAccount!.displayName!.toString(),
        email: googleSignInAccount.email,
        mobile: 0,
        profilePicture: googleSignInAccount.photoUrl != ''
            ? googleSignInAccount.photoUrl
            : profilePic,
        followers: [],
        following: [],
        token: '',
        deviceToken: deviceToken!,
        createdAt: '',
      );

      http.Response res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('$url/api/signup'),
        body: user.toJson(),
        headers: <String, String>{
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        },
      );

      if (context.mounted) {
        httpErrorHanding(
          res: res,
          context: context,
          onSuccess: () async {
            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            await prefs.setString(
                'x-access-token', jsonDecode(res.body)['token']);
            ref!.read(userProvider.notifier).updateUser(res.body);
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => BottomBar(data: 0),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackbar(context, e.toString());
    }
  }```
````

No problem is showing in Sign when I try on my Real device or my friend's Device Please anyone suggest me how to solve this matter? i also added my SHA key of debug and Release mode of my app in Firebase and also saved goole-service .json in *app* section

Comment: Have you checked [**this example**](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart) provided by flutter google_sign_in package to verify the code ?

Comment: Sir I don't understand but can you tell me what I have to check.

Comment: I mean check for the best practices and if possible try with new OAuth client ID from GCP console and give it another try. If it still not worked then please provide more information to trace out the issue.

Comment: This issue is only showing when I upload my app on Playstore they give this in review on my side I try each and every device it works totally fine